# displayname returns null after registration on flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Display name returns null right after registration. However, if i login with the same email id, the display name shows up magically. Looked up some of the answers here but didn't find anything relevant to implementation in flutter.

My Code:

```
Future createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password, String name) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      await userCredential.user.updateProfile(displayName: name);
      print(userCredential.user.displayName);
      User user = userCredential.user;
      db.setProfileonRegistration(user.uid, name);
      return _userFromFireBase(userCredential.user);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
        return null;
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The rest of the function is not waiting for line 6, but you are expecting the code is waiting for successful execution of that line before continue

Instead of using

```
await userCredential.user.updateProfile(displayName: name);
```

Try using this

```
Future createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password, String name) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      
      userCredential.user.updateProfile(displayName: name).then((_) {
        print(userCredential.user.displayName);
        User user = userCredential.user;
        db.setProfileonRegistration(user.uid, name);
        return _userFromFireBase(userCredential.user);
      });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print('The password provided is too weak.');
        return null;
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        print('The account already exists for that email.');
        return null;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

It will wait until

```
userCredential.user.updateProfile(displayName: name)
```

Future resolves and then continues with the rest of the code in the .then block